# Difference between bin/magento c:f and bin/magento c:c cache commands in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, performance, full-page-cache, bin-magento, magento-cache-management

I would like to understand the difference between the bin/magento c:f and bin/magento c:c commands used for cache management in Magento 2. Although they both serve the purpose of clearing the cache, I would like to know their specific functionalities and when it is appropriate to use each command.

What is the purpose of the bin/magento c:f command?

How does bin/magento c:f clear and rebuild the cache in Magento 2?

In what scenarios would I typically use bin/magento c:f instead of bin/magento c:c?

What are the potential implications of running bin/magento c:f on a production environment?

What is the purpose of the bin/magento c:c command?

How does bin/magento c:c clean the cache in Magento 2 without triggering cache regeneration?

When would it be more appropriate to use bin/magento c:c instead of bin/magento c:f?

Are there any considerations or best practices to keep in mind when using bin/magento c:c in a production environment?

I appreciate any insights or explanations that can help me better understand the differences between these two cache management commands in Magento 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Magento 2, the commands `bin/magento c:f` and `bin/magento c:c` are used to clear the cache, but they serve different purposes:

1. `bin/magento c:f` or `bin/magento cache:flush`:
   This command is used to flush all enabled cache types in Magento. It clears the contents of the cache storage and rebuilds the cache when the pages are accessed again. It is typically used when you want to clear all cached data and ensure that the latest changes are reflected on the storefront.

Example usage:

```
bin/magento cache:flush
```

2. `bin/magento c:c` or `bin/magento cache:clean`:
   This command is used to clean the cache. It removes all the contents of the cache, but it does not trigger cache regeneration. The cache files are still present, but they will be re-generated when the pages are accessed. This command is useful when you want to remove the cached data without fully rebuilding it.

Example usage:

```
bin/magento cache:clean
```